# Ansible, mysql connection refused while running command from docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, ansible, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to run Laravel project and want use ansible for deployment and also to simplify configuration process for local environment

Here is a part of ansible playbook what I'm using and what causing the problem:

```
 # run docker-compose
- name: Run docker containers
  shell: docker-compose -f {{compose_file}} up -d

- name: Docker ps
  shell: docker-compose -f {{compose_file}} ps
  register: lists

- name: Print docker ps
  debug: msg="{{lists.stdout_lines}}"

# run migrations
- name: Run migrations
  shell: docker-compose -f {{compose_file}} exec -T --user {{wwwdata}} workspace sh -c 'cd {{remote_basedir}} && php artisan migrate --seed'
```

Output:

```
TASK [Run docker containers] *************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Docker ps] *************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Print docker ps] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "          Name                         Command               State                 Ports               ", 
        "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", 
        "docker_applications_1   /true                            Exit 0                                    ", 
        "docker_mailcatcher_1    mailcatcher --foreground - ...   Up       25/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1080->80/tcp     ", 
        "docker_mysql_1          docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up       0.0.0.0:33066->3306/tcp          ", 
        "docker_nginx_1          nginx -g daemon off;             Exit 1                                    ", 
        "docker_php_1            docker-php-entrypoint php- ...   Up       0.0.0.0:7778->7778/tcp, 9000/tcp ", 
        "docker_redis_cache_1    docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up       6379/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6380->6380/tcp ", 
        "docker_redis_disk_1     docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up       0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp           ", 
        "docker_workspace_1      docker-php-entrypoint php- ...   Up       9000/tcp                         "
    ]
}

TASK [Run migrations] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "docker-compose -f /var/www/project/docker/docker-compose.yml exec -T --user www-data workspace sh -c 'cd /var/www/vhosts/project && php artisan migrate --seed'", "delta": "0:00:01.333487", "end": "2017-11-01 17:13:08.772027", "failed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2017-11-01 17:13:07.438540", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "\n                                                                               \n  [Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException]                                         \n  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_s  \n  chema.tables where table_schema = database and table_name = migrations)           \n                                                                               \n\n                                             \n  [PDOException]                             \n  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  \n                                             ", "stdout_lines": ["", "                                                                               ", "  [Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException]                                         ", "  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_s  ", "  chema.tables where table_schema = database and table_name = migrations)           ", "                                                                               ", "", "                                             ", "  [PDOException]                             ", "  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  ", "                                             "]}
    to retry, use: --limit @/var/www/project/ansible_playbooks/install.retry

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=12   changed=11   unreachable=0    failed=1
```

As you can see it failing when I run `docker-compose -f /var/www/adgate/project/docker/docker-compose.yml exec -T --user www-data rtb_workspace sh -c 'cd /var/www/vhosts/project && php artisan migrate --seed'` with error `Connection refused` but container exists and when I run same command manually in terminal all working fine.

Thank you for any response!

Comment: Try adding a sleep and check, this may be timing issue

Comment: hm, ` - pause: seconds: 60`  after task where I running `docker-compose up`  working but it's not a solution I think because when it run by a very first time it takes much more time to build images. And why in such case `docker ps` task showing that container is active?

Comment: There is difference between container being up and a service inside the container being up. Container up will be just few ms, but mysql itself may take few seconds to be ready to accept connections. You can use something like https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it to check if the service is really up and execute command and based on the same.

Comment: ahh, lol you are right I did not think about that for some reason. Let me check, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Tarun Lalwani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830850/tarun-lalwani) I start moving to right way, instead of using bash script proposed by him I made it with ansible in such way

```
- name: wait for mysql container
  retries: 5
  delay: 5
  shell: docker-compose -f {{compose_file}} exec -T  mysql sh -c 'mysql --user=db_user --password=secret -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | grep -c database'
  register: mysql_alive
  until: mysql_alive.rc == 0
```